# How to simplify two annotation into one

Tags: java, annotations

I want to simplify this

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class Struts2ActionClass{
    ...
}
```

to this

```
@Struts2Action
public class Struts2ActionClass{
...
}
```

attempt to avoid foggetting the `@Scope("prototype")`

Dose anyone have any idea?

---

Update:

I did this copy the code of @Controller,it seems worked.

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public @interface Struts2Action {
}
```

But why?

Comment: Because that how it works in java.

Answer (score 1):

> I did this copy the code of @Controller,it seems worked.
>
> ```
> @Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @Controller
> @Scope("prototype")
> public @interface Struts2Action {
> }
> ```

It works because that's the way to combine annotations. So now you don't need to write every annotation (Controller, Scope etc.), just the parent one (Struts2Action)